# Can I use Azure SignalR Local Emulator for ASP.NET web applications as well?

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

Just learned about Azure SignalR Local Emulator and I'd like to use it for local testing. I have an ASP.NET web application and an Azure Functions project which both are Azure SignalR service clients. I've generated the connection string but when i pass it to my web application i immediately receive:

```
fail: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer[2]
      Hub 'Ta****Hub' is now disconnected from '(Primary)http://localhost:8889(hub=Ta****Hub)'. Please check log for detailed info.
```

Is the Azure SignalR Local Emulator supposed to work in setups like this one? If yes, how can i possibly configure it? I'd guess that it might be related to the upstream setting, i use a default one:

```
Current Upstream Settings:
        [0]http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/signalr(event:'*',hub:'*',category:'*')
```

Should i add another one for the web app? Or am i getting all this completely wrong?